# Export MySQL to CSV using UNIX

Tags: mysql, unix

Is it possible to Export a MySQL to a CSV using the command line in UNIX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: you almost beat the 30 second rule - they should award badges for that type of victory

Answer (score 1):

If you have Ruby, you can use the [mysql2xxxx](https://github.com/seamusabshere/mysql2xxxx) gem

```
gem install mysql2xxxx
mysql2csv --username=root --password=password --execute "select * from mytable" > mytable.csv
```

It's not as fast as mysqldump, but you don't need to be on the same computer as the MySQL server. It also provides mysql2xml and mysql2json.